# Java Arrays Game Shop

Tags: java, arrays

I've just started writing Java and I'm trying to make a simulation of a game shop and I have an array that prints the values of each item to purchase. For each index of the array there's a name of the item. For example, Jewel of Open has a price of 500. How can I attach a string name to the price for each array index? I could printf each instance of medicineList by calling it's subscript and attaching it's item name but that would replace the purpose of the for loop. I'm interested in seeing if there's another way to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the method:

```
public static int purchaseMedicine(int goldAmount) {

    int[] medicineList = {500, 800, 2000, 8000, 4000, 200, 200};
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < medicineList.length; i++) {

        System.out.printf("%d\n", medicineList[i]);
    }

    System.out.printf("\tGold %d\n\n", goldAmount);
    return i; // Returns the instances of medicineList
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I attach a string name to the price for each array index?

You can use Java's [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). This allows you to map string names to integer costs:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Jewel of Open", 500);
map.put("Jewel of Close", 800);
map.put("Jewel of Slightly Ajar", 1200);
```

To retrieve values you can use:

```
map.get("Jewel of Open"); //and this will return 500
```

This *slightly edited* bit **from Binyamin's answer** answers your comments question

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " costs " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I like the idea. Would it be possible for me to print those values through a for loop and call those names as well?

Comment: Another poster had answered this question in his answer. I've added it to mine

Comment: I love this! I really appreciate this, I would've never have known about this. Another problem I'm trying to solve is figuring out how to generate a more reasonable amount of gold. The highest item price in the game is 500,000. I have this:    Random gold = new Random();    int goldAmount = gold.nextInt(500000) + 1;

Answer (score 2):

Ideally create a Class. lets say. Game, with a name and price,

```
class Game {
  public String name;
  public int price;

  Game(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game[] medicineList = { new Game ("Skyrim", 500), new Game("Jewel of Open", 400) };

    for(int i = 0; i < medicineList.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%d\n", medicineList[i].price);
    }

  }
}
```

The advantage of using a Class is that later on you can easily add more properties to it, like Ratings for example, without changing much code.

Comment: It's giving me a weird error on this line: Game[] medicineList = { new Game('Skyrim', 500), //and so forth..};

Comment: I've corrected and updated the answer with a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> prices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
prices.add("Skyrim", 500);
prices.add("GTA", 800);
///....
```

Then you can iterate over the map:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : prices.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " costs " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create 2 arrays.

```
public static int purchaseMedicine(int goldAmount) {

    int[] medicineList = {500, 800, 2000, 8000, 4000, 200, 200};
    String[] name = { "names here" };

    for(int i = 0; i < medicineList.length; i++) {

        System.out.printf(name[i] +  medicineList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Jewel of Open,Potion, High Potion, Elixir, Manna Prism, Antivenom, Uncurse, Hammer, Library Card500Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 'd'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2432)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
 at castlevania.purchaseMedicine(castlevania.java:64)
 at castlevania.main(castlevania.java:22)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KKctKgyB Here is what I have so far, sorry if the indentation is off from pasting it into the editor.

Comment: You have to seperate each item as a string.. `String[] medicineNames = {"Jewel of Open,Potion, High Potion, Elixir, Manna Prism, Antivenom, Uncurse, Hammer, Library Card"};` change it to `String[] medicineNames = {"Jewel of Open","Potion", "High Potion", "Elixir", "Manna Prism", "Antivenom", "Uncurse", "Hammer", "Library Card"};`

Comment: I'm going to run and compile this as soon as I can and let you know how it comes out.

Comment: It worked, but I spent a few more hours playing with my options. I came to like the hash map feature.